# What's with the final/const craze in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Java have `final` as well as Dart, but as far as I have seen, most Java people avoid using it all the time, since it can make your code less readable. For example, `final` is used all the time in `class` constants such as `public static final int`, but most people avoid using it in a method variable, since it's just seen as "excessive code correctness" by many developers, adding to boilerplate code.

C++ also has `const` and it can get crazy with it:

```
char ** const * const x // declare x as const pointer to const pointer to pointer to char
```

Now I am starting to learn Flutter and I am seeing `final` and `const` all over the place. Are those really necessary, like when they say:

> Fields in a Widget subclass are always marked "final".

Or can they be treated as "excess of code correctness" and be removed?

Sorry if maybe my question is too stupid, I am really new to Dart and Flutter and I don't know all the side effects/benefits of using `final` and `const`, to justify the additional attention of when to remember to use them in my code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`const` means that the value of the variable is known at compile time and it is going to be constant for the whole duration of the application.

Since the value is known at compile time, you can make the necessary optimisations.

`final` means that the value will be constant or immutable from the moment it is set. But it is set at runtime. So you don't know it at compile time and you can't optimise it.

If you don't use `final` you lose the immutability feature to what you should adhere in Flutter. You should always create a widget, not modify it. And the way to enforce that is to make all its fields final.

Comment: Why Widgets have to have `final` for their fields then? I could just omitt the `final` and have less boilerplate

Comment: Yes, you can omit them and it will work. But then you lose the immutability feature to what you should adhere. You should always create a widget, not modify it. And a way to enforce that is to make all its fields final.

Comment: While an immutable object must have `final` members, `final x` does not make `x` immutable.  It means only that `x` cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 11):

All these finals are not here just for fun. Flutter revolves around immutability. `final`  is a neat way to enforce that immutability, ensuring you are correctly following the different design patterns.

They are definitely not "excess of correctness" no. They exists to assure a maintainable app. 2 characters is absolutely worth the effort

Comment: No because `var` versus `final `

Comment: Ohh right lol, I am still beginning to learn, still on a Java mindset

Answer (score 8):

The main upside of using `const` is that, in a reactive UI like Flutter where large parts of the widget tree may be rebuilt regularly, every single object (and all of its own variables) of every single widget will need to be recreated on every rebuild, **except if they are marked `const`**, in which case the same instance will be reused throughout the lifetime of the app.

Even with a moderately complex UI this will quickly save thousands of object instantiations, which can be significant especially when animating widgets. So, it is considered a good practice to use `const` when possible.

`final` is different, it doesn't bring any performance benefits and is mainly a way to ensure that you are following Flutter design patterns. In my opinion it improves readability in the way that knowing quickly what is immutable and what is not can be very important when developing with Flutter.

Comment: Yes, but I tried to `const` everything possible and my code lost a lot of readability and became tedious to develop, while the performance benefits can't be seen in modern hardware. I am not saying I am against it, just a balanced analysis

Comment: Why do you say that it loses readability? It used to be painful before Dart 2 where you had to write `const` for every single object but now there's no need to `const` everything in an object already marked `const`, it is implicit. Performance benefits can be seen when doing complex animations where part of the widget tree is rebuilt on every frame (else you may see the animation stuttering).

Comment: I agree on animations, but I was talking more about passing all colors as const and etc (I won't remember all options here, but I remember there were plenty), also several widgets that could be const. There's a linter option to raise a warning whenever something is not a const, and if I tried to obey it my code became horrible, and for parts that just update once and never again.

Comment: Yes, I agree that when performance doesn't matter, it is better to aim for readability. I was just surprised that it caused such a loss of readability.

Comment: I agree too... I have over loaded variables and called setState() like a thousand times... and besides animations- there was little or no performance diff! You've gotta realize, the dart VM has to be able to take on the efficiency of guys like JVM... and if that can do it without jumping over hoops, Im sure guys who built the Dart VM are not shying away!